# Top and Bottom image is cropped in a bubble chart

Tags: tableau-api

I am using tableau for visualization. In one of my dashboard, i am creating a bubble chart for displaying no of population growth on Y-o-Y, based on the data  from the extracts.

This dashboard shows different bubbles calculated based on each year. On clicking each bubble, it will display the additional data information inside the bubble for the year. The other bubbles in the dashboard will be grayed-out.

Everything is working good. But i could see that, when i click one bubble, the top and bottom position in bubble is getting cropped off. The other bubbles are getting grayed-off as normal.

Note: I need to display 4 dashboards in one visualization as per guidelines. Maybe the height and width used for dashboards could be an issue.

All i want to know is, whether this is default behavior since tableau takes height and width automatically in my visualizations?

[image: Bubble Chart Visualization]

[image: Cropping Issue when i click one bubble from my chart]

Thanks,

Comment: maybe it's just not clear to me, but may I ask you to upload 2 better (and  bigger) images? one before and one after your click on the bubble?

Comment: @FabioFantoni: I have added two images to this thread. I not sure, if it is a known tableau behavior.

Comment: Can you tried to set "Entire View" for this work sheet so it should be show all the things? Please provide more detail screen shot of your dashboard which shows width and height.

Comment: @KuldipMCA: I tried setting it up. I am seeing this issue in entire view too.